# MySQL error when editing product in Magento

Tags: mysql, magento, indexing

it's a v 1.4.1.1 Magento, upgraded from a v 1.3.2.4
When I try to edit a product an error message appears:

```
exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '6028-0-2' for key 'PRIMARY''
```

And if I try to reindex prices I have the same message in exception.log
I think the problem is in the catalog_product_website table, because if I delete the row, I can run the price indexing, but as I try to edit the product to assign it a website, I get the same message.
A weird thing is that catalog_product_website table has only 2 columns, and the exception talks about a 3 primary keys table (right?)
Here is the whole stack trace:

```
2010-12-07T12:12:41+00:00 ERR (3):
exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '6028-0-2' for key 'PRIMARY'' in /var/www/ortoweb1314/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/ortoweb1314/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/ortoweb1314/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(468): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/ortoweb1314/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#3 /var/www/ortoweb1314/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(333): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /var/www/ortoweb1314/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Indexer/Price/Default.php(260): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#5 /var/www/ortoweb1314/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Indexer/Price/Default.php(133): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Indexer_Price_Default->_prepareFinalPriceData('6028')
#6 /var/www/ortoweb1314/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Indexer/Price.php(192): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Indexer_Price_Default->reindexEntity('6028')
#7 /var/www/ortoweb1314/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(144): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Indexer_Price->catalogProductSave(Object(Mage_Index_Model_Event))
#8 /var/www/ortoweb1314/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Price.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->callEventHandler(Object(Mage_Index_Model_Event))
#9 /var/www/ortoweb1314/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(85): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Price->_processEvent(Object(Mage_Index_Model_Event))
#10 /var/www/ortoweb1314/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(185): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->processEvent(Object(Mage_Index_Model_Event))
#11 [internal function]: Mage_Index_Model_Process->processEvent(Object(Mage_Index_Model_Event))
#12 /var/www/ortoweb1314/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer.php(252): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#13 /var/www/ortoweb1314/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer.php(154): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer->_runAll('processEvent', Array)
#14 /var/www/ortoweb1314/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer.php(219): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer->indexEvent(Object(Mage_Index_Model_Event))
#15 /var/www/ortoweb1314/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php(525): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer->processEntityAction(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 'catalog_product', 'save')
#16 [internal function]: Mage_Catalog_Model_Product->afterCommitCallback()
#17 /var/www/ortoweb1314/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(104): call_user_func(Array)
#18 /var/www/ortoweb1314/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(310): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract->commit()
#19 /var/www/ortoweb1314/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(663): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#20 /var/www/ortoweb1314/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->saveAction()
#21 /var/www/ortoweb1314/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
#22 /var/www/ortoweb1314/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(177): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#23 /var/www/ortoweb1314/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(304): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#24 /var/www/ortoweb1314/app/Mage.php(596): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#25 /var/www/ortoweb1314/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#26 {main}
```

I hope someone can help me, I really out of idea right now :(

**edit**: I've enhanced the exception log's message so I can see the whole query, and here it is:

```
#2 /var/www/ortoweb1314/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query(
    "INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp` SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `cg`.`customer_group_id`, `cw`.`website_id`, ta_tax_class_id.value AS `tax_class_id`, ta_price.value AS `orig_price`, IF(IF(ta_special_from_date.value IS NULL, 1, IF(DATE(ta_special_from_date.value) <= cwd.date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(ta_special_to_date.value IS NULL, 1, IF(DATE(ta_special_to_date.value) >= cwd.date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND ta_special_price.value < ta_price.value, ta_special_price.value, ta_price.value) AS `price`, IF(IF(ta_special_from_date.value IS NULL, 1, IF(DATE(ta_special_from_date.value) <= cwd.date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(ta_special_to_date.value IS NULL, 1, IF(DATE(ta_special_to_date.value) >= cwd.date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND ta_special_price.value < ta_price.value, ta_special_price.value, ta_price.value) AS `min_price`, IF(IF(ta_special_from_date.value IS NULL, 1, IF(DATE(ta_special_from_date.value) <= cwd.date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND IF(ta_special_to_date.value IS NULL, 1, IF(DATE(ta_special_to_date.value) >= cwd.date, 1, 0)) > 0 AND ta_special_price.value < ta_price.value, ta_special_price.value, ta_price.value) AS `max_price`, tp.min_price AS `tier_price`, tp.min_price AS `base_tier` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `customer_group` AS `cg`
 INNER JOIN `core_website` AS `cw`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_website` AS `cwd` ON cw.website_id = cwd.website_id
 INNER JOIN `core_store_group` AS `csg` ON csg.website_id = cw.website_id AND cw.default_group_id = csg.group_id
 INNER JOIN `core_store` AS `cs` ON csg.default_store_id = cs.store_id AND cs.store_id != 0
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `pw` ON pw.product_id = e.entity_id AND pw.website_id = cw.website_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_index_tier_price` AS `tp` ON tp.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tp.website_id = cw.website_id AND tp.customer_group_id = cg.customer_group_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tad_status` ON tad_status.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_status.attribute_id = 80 AND tad_status.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `tas_status` ON tas_status.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tas_status.attribute_id = 80 AND tas_status.store_id = cs.store_id
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `ta_tax_class_id` ON ta_tax_class_id.entity_id = e.entity_id AND ta_tax_class_id.attribute_id = 81 AND ta_tax_class_id.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `ta_price` ON ta_price.entity_id = e.entity_id AND ta_price.attribute_id = 60 AND ta_price.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `ta_special_price` ON ta_special_price.entity_id = e.entity_id AND ta_special_price.attribute_id = 61 AND ta_special_price.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `ta_special_from_date` ON ta_special_from_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND ta_special_from_date.attribute_id = 62 AND ta_special_from_date.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `ta_special_to_date` ON ta_special_to_date.entity_id = e.entity_id AND ta_special_to_date.attribute_id = 63 AND ta_special_to_date.store_id = 0
 INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `ciss` ON ciss.product_id = e.entity_id AND ciss.website_id = cw.website_id WHERE (e.type_id='simple') AND (IF(tas_status.value_id > 0, tas_status.value, tad_status.value)=1) AND (e.entity_id IN('6028')) AND (ciss.stock_status=1)",
    array(
    ),
)
```

the whole excpetion.log file is here: http://www.dowhiletrue.net/exception.txt.tar.gz

Comment: parloir how did you perform your upgrade?  Did you do it from the command line? I just upgraded 1.3 to 1.4 a couple of weeks ago and it was a nightmare.  The trick I learned is that you have to backup your database, create an entirely new database, load in the data you backed up and then do a fresh install (I tried i numerous other ways first and always ran into foreign key conflicts till I did it the way described above).

Comment: well, actually I deleted all v1.3 files and replace them by a v1.4, and then I ran the install, connecting to the db I used for 1.3

Comment: That could be your problem.  I tried NOT deleting the database and I always got key errors.  Something happens when you delete the database that gets rid of the key conflicts.  If you haven't tried it yet, I'd try the approach outlined here http://www.webshopapps.com/blog/2010/02/upgrading-magento-to-version-1-4-keeping-it-simple/  Take my advice, don't skip any steps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem is not in `catalog_product_website` table. The problem in price index table, maybe there some old records from previous version, that should be deleted. I would recommend you to reindex all the indexes. The full reindex process clears index table first and then it fulfill the table with data. It should help.

If full reindex is not helping, then it is possible that your installment has modules that observe `prepare_catalog_product_price_index_table` event, which modifies re-index select in a way of additional join that multiplies number of rows with the same primary key. It also may cause such an error.

Cheers,
Ivan

Comment: hi Ivan, thx for answering. I did the full reindex, empty cache/session/locks directories, then edit the product and again, same error :(

Comment: I also search for prepare_catalog_product_price_index_table in app/ directory, and it only appears in CatalogRule/etc/config.xml (besides from the dispatchEvents). I delete the catalog rule I had, again emptied all var/ directories, but again, same message...
Any more thoughts?

Comment: dump your database, recreate it and import the dump in again and see if it solves your issues

Comment: @anton: actually, the db I'm working with is a dump from prod that I dumped this morning... but I'll try it anyway. I'll keep you posted

Comment: From your stack trace I see that the source of the problem in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Indexer_Price_Default::_prepareFinalPriceData()` method, try also to look for this event `prepare_catalog_product_index_select`

Comment: well, there is only one oserver listening to this event, CatalogInventory (in app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/config.xml).

Comment: I also notice that the observe just before (catalog_product_website_update) is comented, but I haven't comented it myself, the core files are genuine. I don't know if this will be related, but as my problem is about product and website, I wonder...

Comment: Ok, so maybe you can contact me and we can arrange a GoToMeeting session for finding the possible problem? ichepurnyi at ecomdev dot org

Comment: how did you solve this problem? can you please help me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

As stupid as this sounds, since you are getting duplicated -- auto_incremented -- keys, have you tried incrementing your auto_increment value for that table? Assuming this is a conflicted DB state in some way, this would fix the issue. If you jump the PK by 100 and you *still* get PK violations, then the code is probably attempting to insert the same record twice.

This would be the relevant query:

```
ALTER TABLE catalog_product_website AUTO_INCREMENT=1234
```

Comment: Seems there is complex primary key containing `product_id`, `customer_group_id` and `website_id`

Comment: hi Joseph, I've edited my question, as now I can see the whole un-truncated trace. we can see now that the problem lies into catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp table, which has no auto_increment value